# how can I get google fit data's

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit

Hi how can I get the activity from google fit data. I have almost done all aspects after getting the access token how can I get the google fit datas, by using the below code I can get only this kind of response

code:

```
  gFit.listExistingSessions(req.query.token,function(status,data){
  //    console.log('Sessions',data);
    res.render('results', { resp: data });
  });
```

response:

```
"session": [
  {
   "id": "3116a82009dd6cd7:activemode:running:1456064572752",
   "startTimeMillis": "1456064572752",
   "endTimeMillis": "1456114372880",
   "modifiedTimeMillis": "1456745578987",
   "application": {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
   },
   "activityType": 8
  },
  {
   "id": "3116a82009dd6cd7:activemode:running:1456064572752",
   "name": "Evening running",
   "startTimeMillis": "1456064572752",
   "endTimeMillis": "1456114370411",
   "modifiedTimeMillis": "1456745578992",
   "application": {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
   },
   "activityType": 8
  },
  {
   "id": "3116a82009dd6cd7:activemode:biking:1456742139081",
   "startTimeMillis": "1456742139081",
   "endTimeMillis": "1456742187907",
   "modifiedTimeMillis": "1456745578998",
   "application": {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
   },
   "activityType": 1
  }
]
```

Can any one tell me how to get the calories burned, steps count, miles and minutes of each of the sessions.

Comment: Are you using the [Official node client for Google APIs](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/fitness/v1.js) ?

Comment: yes, I have registered in  google development console

Comment: According to some [official Android example app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistorySessions/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistorysessions/MainActivity.java#L353), it seems you need to specify what parameters from the session you want. In the example they are retrieving the speed. I will see if I can find more info on this.

Comment: From their [Platform basics page](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/sessions):
  
`Sessions in Google Fit consist of a start time, an end time, a user-friendly name, a description, an activity type, and a unique identifier. Sessions do not contain fitness data themselves. You can think of sessions as metadata objects with information that helps you query data from the fitness store later.` So pretty much you have to query for a sessions list, and then retrieve the datasets that fall between the timestamps of each session in order to retrieve the detailed data.

Comment: Are you tell me in this way: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input/datasets/1451606400000000000-1455888676947965751?access_token=****

Comment: From this I can get this as response: By this I can get only:{"minStartTimeNs": "1451606400000000000",
"maxEndTimeNs": "1455888676947965751", "dataSourceId":"raw:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", "point": [ {
"startTimeNanos": "1455859800000000000",
"endTimeNanos": "1455860400000000000",
"dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
"value": [
{"intVal": 10
}
   ],
   "modifiedTimeMillis": "1455866857804"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104872/discussion-between-vg-and-lemavri).

Answer (score 1):

According to [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/sessions#benefits_of_using_sessions), sessions are only a mean of organizing workouts, but they do not provide specific workout data. For that, you have to query datasets that overlap with the [time interval of the session](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/sessions#creating_and_reading_sessions).

For more information on how to query specific datasets, see [Working with datasets](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/datasets).

This is the example request for querying datasets:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:1234567890:Example%20Manufacturer:ExampleTablet:1000001/datasets/1397513334728708316-1397515179728708316
```

There, you have to replace `com.google.step_count.delta` with whatever [data type](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/data-types) you require, and also replace the timestamps at the end of the query with the ones that match your session start and end times.